# FM signal example

Tags: signal, modulation, frequency-modulation

Sorry if this question is too basic, but I'm a software engineer student who must study communication systems.

I try to represent a FM signal in a [graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), but I don't know why the result looks differently from the book.

Here are the expressions:

1. Carrier:

   c(t) = Vc * cos[2PIfct + K * m(t)]
2. Information signal:

   m(t) = Vm * cos(2PIfmt)
3. Deviation sensibility

   K = 2 Hz/V
4. Amplitudes and frequencies:

   - Vc = 4V
   - Vm = 2V
   - fc = 10 Hz
   - fm = 1 Hz

This is the image book:
[image]
This is my failed attempt:
[image]

So, my question is: **What am I doing wrong?**

Any helps is appreciated.

Comment: There is no problem at all. You're just looking at more periods, but for me it's clear that yours is an FM signal. Secondly, the book's illustration might just be something exaggereted for the sake of understanding it easier.

Comment: I gave the function $y=4\cdot \cos \left(\left(62.8\cdot x\right)+\left(4\cdot \cos \left(6.28\cdot x\right)\right)\right)$ as input (You can paste it directly). It seems ok to me. The function translates to y = 4cos(62.8x + (4cos 6.28x )) which is nothing but a frequency modulated signal. So maybe its a problem of providing input in apt manner.

Comment: Oh, I'm very happy to hear that @hryghr! You have no idea how hard this is for me... If you ask the question, I'm glad to accept your answer. @Plutoniumsmugglerwithhat thanks for the effort, but I didn't understand you =/

Comment: Try pasting that thing in the input(the one I gave).

Comment: You have right! I zoomed and it looked like an FM signal =) Thanks @Plutoniumsmugglerwithhat

Comment: Actually, you should have c(t)=Vc·cos(2pi·fc·t + K·integrate(m(t), -infinity, t)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem at all. You're just looking at more periods (longer time), but for me it's clear that yours is an FM signal as well. Secondly, the book's illustration might just be something exaggerated for the sake of understanding it easier.